# Can i get all task by inputting asana search url?

Tags: api, url, search, tags, asana

If we search on asana UI we get a unique url to every search. Using that url as input, through asana api can i get all tasks which were found in that url.

for eg. 
Search URL : https://app.asana.com/0/search/12345678/90123456
has got 50 tasks, so through api (using some kind of input as url)  can i get those 50 tasks alone?

NOTE: The search url is nothing but combinations of tags and some filters. I can do search by api searching directly through tags, but this seams little bit easy to get my searched tasks.

Please suggest if any solution.

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently support sorting via the API. The URL contains an ID for the search and an ID for the task currently selected of the form "/0/search/[search id]/[task id]", so you can get the specific task easily with the API.

However, getting the results for the search via the API is not supported.